# How can i redirect to the same page when a function executed Django

Tags: python, django

I have a like function in `views.py` and whenever the function executes I want my user to be returned to the same page he/she was before the funcion executed.

What should I write in `return` of my function?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply return using the same HTML template to the user

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that when `your_function` executes you are in `home` template page, defined as follows in **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
]
```

in **views.py**, at the end of `your_function` script, simply put:

```
return render(request, 'home.html', some_context_dictionary)
```